# Strategy close position in wrong price

Tags: pine-script, pine-script-v5, tradingview-api

Hey guys i writed an strategy and seted tp and sl to 1 percent of price.but sometimes position closes on next candle.anyone can help me

```
if Direction == "Buy"
    if (bullCond or hiddenBullCond) and baze and strategy.opentrades==0
        strategy.order(id = 'buy' , direction = strategy.long )
        tp := strategy.position_avg_price * (1 + tpPerc)
        sl := strategy.position_avg_price * (1 - slPerc)



if Direction == "Sell"
    if (bearCond or hiddenBearCond) and baze and strategy.opentrades==0
        strategy.order(id = 'sellbear' , direction = strategy.short )
        tp := strategy.position_avg_price * (1 - slPerc)
        sl := strategy.position_avg_price * (1 + tpPerc)


strategy.exit(id = 'close' ,limit = tp , stop = sl )


if strategy.opentrades==0
    tp := 0.0
    sl := 0.0
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you mixed your tp and sl in your short calculations.

```
tp := strategy.position_avg_price * (1 - slPerc)
```

Here you are setting the variable `tp` but your are using `slPerc`.

You can actually set those two variables in the global scope. Use `strategy.position_size` to figure out if you are in a long or short position, then set your tp and sl accordingly.

```
if Direction == "Buy"
    if (bullCond or hiddenBullCond) and baze and strategy.opentrades==0
        strategy.order(id = 'buy' , direction = strategy.long )

if Direction == "Sell"
    if (bearCond or hiddenBearCond) and baze and strategy.opentrades==0
        strategy.order(id = 'sellbear' , direction = strategy.short )

is_long = (strategy.position_size > 0)
is_short = (strategy.position_size < 0)
tp := is_long ? strategy.position_avg_price * (1 + tpPerc) : is_short ? strategy.position_avg_price * (1 - tpPerc) : na
sl := is_long ? strategy.position_avg_price * (1 - slPerc) : is_short ? strategy.position_avg_price * (1 + slPerc) : na

if (is_long)
    strategy.exit("Long Exit", "Long", limit = tp , stop = sl)

if (is_short)
    strategy.exit("Short Exit", "Short", limit = tp , stop = sl)
```